# Displaying div elements onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs : `#mosaic-content` & `#mosaic-content-1`.
Initially, when the loads, `#mosaic-content` will be displayed with a class `.active` and `#mosaic-content-1` will be hidden.

I have 4 links:

```
Home
Event
Gallery
About
```

The div `#mosaic-content-1` should be displayed only when the user clicks on `About`. For all the other 3 clicks, it has to remain hidden.
I wrote the following code to achieve this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#mosaic-content").addClass("active");
    $("#mosaic-content-1").hide();
});
$("#home, #event, #gallery").click(function () {    
    $("#mosaic-content").show();
    $("#mosaic-content").addClass("active");
    $("#mosaic-content-1").hide();
    $("#mosaic-content-1").removeClass("active");

});
$("#about").click(function () { 
    $("#mosaic-content").hide();
    $("#mosaic-content").removeClass("active");
    $("#mosaic-content-1").show();
    $("#mosaic-content-1").addClass("active");
});
```

However, in the above code, if `#mosaic-content` is shown and then the user clicks Event or Gallery, the functions are run again, which makes my website a bit slow( The `divs` are full with a lot of `HTML content`).

Is there any better way of achieving this?

Comment: hi..can you plz provide me .active class code...

Comment: .toggle() (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) could be more efficient? That's how I tend to hide/show stuff anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.is(':visible')` to check if the div is already visible

```
$(function () {
    $("#mosaic-content").addClass("active");
    $("#mosaic-content-1").hide();
});
$("#home, #event, #gallery").click(function () {   
if(!$("#mosaic-content").is(':visible')){
    $("#mosaic-content").show();
    $("#mosaic-content").addClass("active");
    $("#mosaic-content-1").hide();
    $("#mosaic-content-1").removeClass("active");
}

});
$("#about").click(function () { 
if($("#mosaic-content").is(':visible')){
    $("#mosaic-content").hide();
    $("#mosaic-content").removeClass("active");
    $("#mosaic-content-1").show();
    $("#mosaic-content-1").addClass("active");
}
});
```

Comment: I would be surprised if this sped things up. `is(':visible')` is much more resource-intensive than showing, hiding and adding classes.

Comment: If whenever he shows the item, also adds the active class, then why not just check for hasClass('active') rather than is(':visible')?

Answer (score 0):

Use classes, not id's.

Hide as default block .mosaic-content-1:

```
$(".mosaic-content-1").hide();
```

After show block .mosaic-content

```
$(".mosaic-content").show();
```

Onlick functions in block navigation:

```
$(".navigation a").click(function() {
   if(!$(this).hasClass("about");) {
      $(".navigation a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(".mosaic-content-1").hide();
      $(".mosaic-content").show();
      } else {
          $(".navigation a").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $(".mosaic-content").hide();
          $(".mosaic-content-1").show();
      }

});
```